# Enum in angular form control types?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, types, enums

I am having issues using enums in form types.

the following code:

```
export enum Frequency {
  DAILY = 'DAILY',
  WEEKLY = 'WEEKLY',
  MONTHLY = 'MONTHLY',
  QUARTERLY = 'QUARTERLY',
  HALF_YEARLY = 'HALF_YEARLY',
  YEARLY = 'YEARLY',
}

export type MyForm = FormGroup <{
  frequency: FormControl<Frequency>,
}>

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public form: MyForm = new FormGroup({
    frequency: new FormControl(Frequency.DAILY),
  })

}
```

gives the error:

```
Type 'FormGroup<{ frequency: FormControl<Frequency.DAILY>; }>' is not assignable to type 'MyForm'.
Type 'FormControl<Frequency>' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<Frequency.DAILY>'.
Type 'Frequency' is not assignable to type 'Frequency.DAILY'.
```

stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsb4nb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing `FormGroup` from your type and moving it to the `form` variable like this:

```
export type MyForm = {
  frequency: FormControl<Frequency>;
};

public form: FormGroup<MyForm> = new FormGroup<MyForm>({
  frequency: new FormControl(Frequency.DAILY),
});
```

The returned `new FormGroup` doesn't need to be typed as a `formGroup` as it is already defined as a new `FormGroup`, you only need to type it's controls.

Here is a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o7dt7y?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: This worked thank you. if I could ask, is there a way to do this with formBuilder? Should I even be using formBuilder anymore since it seems I need to clarify the type of form anyways.

Comment: Check this article on https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-typed-forms/ . With formBuilder it is a little bit different but you could still define the formControl types as in the article.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// DEFINE ENUMS
enum Frequency {
  DAYLY,
  MONTHLY,
  YEARLY,
}

// INCLUDE THEM IN CONST OBJECT TYPE DEFINITION
export const periodMap: Record<Frequency, string> = {
  [Frequency.DAYLY]: 'DAILY',
  [Frequency.MONTHLY]: 'MONTHLY', // WE NEED THE TYPE OF THIS
  [Frequency.YEARLY]: 'YEARLY',
};

export type MyForm = FormGroup<{
  // THE MAGIC: ACCESS THE STRING TYPE IN THE periodMap such as 'MONTHLY'

  frequency: FormControl<typeof periodMap[keyof typeof periodMap]>;
}>;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public form: MyForm = new FormGroup({
    frequency: new FormControl(periodMap[Frequency.DAYLY]), // Frequency control has string type.

  });

  constructor() {}
}
```

[stackblitz link for your convenience and for other people](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qklzq3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think its very useful and I know i will use it eventually, however for this case I think the other answer it good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FormBuilder

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private fb: FormBiulder)

  public form: MyForm = this.fb.group({
    frequency: this.fb.control(Frequency.DAILY)
  })

}
```